# .NET8 MAUI iOS app only launches on iPhone when plugged into Mac and launched via VS 22 Debugger

Tags: .net, iphone, maui, .net-8.0

I am encountering an issue with a .NET MAUI app on iOS where the app launches successfully only when the iPhone is plugged into the Mac and launched via Visual Studio Debugger. If I try to launch the app with the iPhone unplugged, it fails to start after displaying the splash screen, without any error or crash logs. **I deploy a debug build from VS to the device and it runs OK. Then when I detach the cable and launch the same build on the device it shows the splash screen and then crashes**

Here are some details about my environment:

Operating System: Sonoma 14.1.2
Visual Studio for Mac: 17.6.8 (build 400)
.NET: 8.0.101

I am seeking guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Has anyone encountered a similar problem with .NET MAUI on iOS, and if so, how did you address it? Any insights or suggestions on debugging this issue would be greatly appreciated.

I have attempted to launch a .NET MAUI iOS app on my Mac using Visual Studio Debugger. When the iPhone is connected via USB to the Mac and I launch the app, it works as expected, displaying the splash screen and proceeding to run successfully.

However, when I unplug the iPhone and attempt to launch the app without the debugger, the app fails to start after displaying the splash screen. There are no error messages or crash logs to indicate the source of the issue.

I expected the app to launch successfully even when the iPhone is unplugged. I have this issue since I updated from .NET7 to .NET8

Everything works fine on Android.

Comment: Can the problem be because I am using .NET8 x64 instead of .NET8 ARM64 ?

Comment: You need .net8 arm64 if your mac uses Apple Silicon chip eg M1, M2 etc

Comment: @IsidorosMoulas i have 2,6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7. So .NET x64 should work fine right ?

Comment: Right you need .net x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have detached the cable from the device and launched the same build on the device and it crashed. It's hard to detect or figure out where the problem is as there's no log file for it.

The issue could be caused by the installed NuGet packages and their settlements. Or this issue could be a problem with Visual Studio, so we ask that you use the VS feedback tool to report the issue. By using the Report a Problem tool, you can collect detailed information about the problem, and send it to Microsoft with just a few button clicks.

Go to the [Visual Studio for Mac feedback tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/report-a-problem?view=vsmac-2022) to report the issue.

Hope this helps!